# Python BMI Calculator I cannot figure out the issue.

Tags: python, calculator

So I get this error when I run the program, I am not sure why this is not working.

C:\Python27>python bmi.py
  File "bmi.py", line 11
    def getweight(wt)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
print('BMI Calculator!')
#declaring my variables
ht=height
wt=weight
bm=bmi
#Calling my main function
main()

#getting user input for weight in pounds
def getweight(wt)
    weight = int(input('Please enter your weight input pounds(whole number):    '))
return(wt)

#getting user input for height in inches
def getheight(ht)
    height = int(input('Please enter your height input in inches(whole number): '))  
return(ht)

#function for the bmi calculator 
def bmicalc()
    bmi = (wt*703)/(ht*ht)

#main function  
def main()
getweight()
getheight()
bmicalc()
```

Comment: You have numerous problems: incorrect indentation, missing colons for the `def` statements, and undefined variables. Please read through a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a colon at the end of your function declaration. Like so:

```
def foo(bar):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks added the colon, the indentation is correct it just looks foobar on the  copy paste of the code. I am still trying to figure out how to post on here.